# Display coordinates of points in DMS format in print composer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling, degrees-minutes-seconds

In QGIS 2.14.2 I have a series of polylines of which I want the start and endpoint to be labeled with its coordinates in WGS84 (EPSG 4326) like this: 51*15'23.40"N, 5*17'56.58"E

I thought I figured a workaround by:

1. Creating new point shapefile and creating points manually at start and endpoint of each polyline.
2. Open field calculator and create a virtual field "X" containing $x and another containing $Y (Decimals)
3. Label them by X||'\n'||Y

However the field calculator gives me an output like this
X:5.26344964931 Y:51.20551633106

How do I display them in DMS format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in the right direction. What you need to do is use the QGIS expression builder to concatenate a string with the degrees, minutes, seconds, and any symbols you want in between.

This example calculates the $x value, and will work for positive or negative values.

```
(CASE WHEN $x < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END) || floor (abs($x)) || '° ' || floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) ||'\'' || substr( (tostring((((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) - floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60)) * 60),1,5) || '"'
```

You can change the symbol signs, like °, ' and '' to fit any style you need.

Do note though that the resulting field has to be a string.

Answer (score 6):

**Since QGIS 3.4**, there is now a builtin expression to convert a coordinate into DMS or DM format.

```
to_dms( $x, 'x', 3) -> 62°31′7.951″
to_dms( $x, 'x', 3, 'suffix') -> 62°31′7.951″E
to_dm( $x, 'x', 5, 'suffix') -> 62°31.13252′E
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you HDunn!

I tweaked the code a little so it also displays North/E oriëntation and has no spaces in the coördinate line:

For field (text string) X:

```
(CASE WHEN $x < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END) || floor (abs($x)) || '°' || floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) ||'\'' || substr( (tostring((((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) - floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60)) * 60),1,5) || '" E'
```

For Y:

```
(CASE WHEN $y < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END) || floor (abs($y)) || '°' || floor(((abs($y)) - floor (abs($y))) * 60) ||'\'' || substr( (tostring((((abs($y)) - floor (abs($y))) * 60) - floor(((abs($y)) - floor (abs($y))) * 60)) * 60),1,5) || '" N'
```

Then to label use:
      "Y"  ||  '\n'  || "X"