# Autoread XY coordinate in 1 field

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes

I'm not familiar with coding.

In QGIS, I would like field attribute to auto populate X and Y value and combine in one field just like highlighted below,

I know that if auto calculate value in field attribute by using $x_at(0) for start X coordinate and $y_at(0) for start Y coordinate,

How to calculate if one field read combination 'Y'N OR 'X'E just like highlighted below?

[image]

---

Has try out this expression $y_at(0) ||  $x_at(0) but turn like below, still not sure how to space between two value with N and E back at each value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I now have the answer from [Display coordinates of points in DMS format in print composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214136/display-coordinates-of-points-in-dms-format-in-print-composer)

and already manipulate base on my situation

```
(CASE WHEN $y_at(0) < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END) || floor (abs($y_at(0))) || '°' || floor(((abs($y_at(0))) - floor (abs($y_at(0)))) * 60) ||'\'' || substr( (tostring((((abs($y_at(0))) - floor (abs($y_at(0)))) * 60) - floor(((abs($y_at(0))) - floor (abs($y_at(0)))) * 60)) * 60),1,5) || '" N'|| '\n' || (CASE WHEN $x_at(0) < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END) || floor (abs($x_at(0))) || '°' || floor(((abs($x_at(0))) - floor (abs($x_at(0)))) * 60) ||'\'' || substr( (tostring((((abs($x_at(0))) - floor (abs($x_at(0)))) * 60) - floor(((abs($x_at(0))) - floor (abs($x_at(0)))) * 60)) * 60),1,5) || '" E'
```

[image]

It works!